# Unexpected behavour when removing an item from an array in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've searched high and low for an answer to this but I just need some human help.

I'm got a simple form where the user can add additional fields. The user can also delete fields that are no longer relevant.

It's the deleting fields that I'm having an issue with.

The fields are rendered from an array within the component's state but when I try to remove an item from the array, it's always the last item in the array that gets removed.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Form_newPriority extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      listName: "",
      rows: [{ id: 1, fieldValue: "" }],
    };
  }

  addrow = () => {
    const rows = [...this.state.rows];
    rows.push({
      id: rows.length + 1,
      fieldValue: "",
    });
    this.setState({ rows: rows });
  };

  removeRow = (idx) => {
    const rows = [...this.state.rows];
    rows.splice(idx, 1);
    this.setState({ rows: rows });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          className="w-full bg-white border border-alice px-4 py-2 mb-1 h-12 rounded-lg"
          type="text"
        ></input>
        <h2>Items:</h2>
        {this.state.rows.map((row, idx) => {
          return (
            <React.Fragment>
              <input
                className="w-half bg-white border border-alice px-4 py-2 mb-4 mr-4  h-12 rounded-lg"
                key={idx}
                type="text"
                placeholder={idx}
              ></input>
              <button
                className="mb-4 text-red-700 inline-block"
                onClick={() => {
                  this.removeRow(idx);
                }}
              >
                Remove
              </button>
            </React.Fragment>
          );
        })}
        <button
          className="bg-alice hover:bg-gray-400 text-c_base text-sm font-bold py-1 px-2 rounded block mr-4"
          onClick={this.addrow}
        >
          Add row
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Form_newPriority;
```

I've also tried

```
rows.filter()
```

but that yeilds the same results.

I'm fairly new to JS and React so am I doing something stupid here?

Comment: The value you are assigning for the input is the index of element mapped, you should include the value of the index in the state and remove the element based on that index, check @Józef Podlecki answer, also when mapping and returning elements for render you should use `key` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

It might look like that it deletes the last element because you are using `index` as identity.

When you use incrementing `id` instead it makes much more sense

**Example**

```js
const { Component, useState, useEffect } = React;

class Form_newPriority extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      listName: "",
      counter: 1,
      rows: [{ id: 1, fieldValue: "" }],
    };
  }

  addrow = () => {
    const rows = [...this.state.rows];
    const counter = this.state.counter + 1;
    rows.push({
      id: counter,
      fieldValue: "",
    });
    this.setState({ counter, rows });
  };

  removeRow = (idx) => {
    const rows = [...this.state.rows];
    rows.splice(idx, 1);
    this.setState({ rows: rows });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          className="w-full bg-white border border-alice px-4 py-2 mb-1 h-12 rounded-lg"
          type="text"
        ></input>
        <h2>Items:</h2>
        {this.state.rows.map((row, idx) => {
          return (
            <React.Fragment key={row.id}>
              <input
                className="w-half bg-white border border-alice px-4 py-2 mb-4 mr-4  h-12 rounded-lg" 
                type="text"
                placeholder={row.id}
              ></input>
              <button
                className="mb-4 text-red-700 inline-block"
                onClick={() => {
                  this.removeRow(idx);
                }}
              >
                Remove
              </button>
            </React.Fragment>
          );
        })}
        <button
          className="bg-alice hover:bg-gray-400 text-c_base text-sm font-bold py-1 px-2 rounded block mr-4"
          onClick={this.addrow}
        >
          Add row
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Form_newPriority />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: It seems that your example exhibts the same issue I'm running into. Could you explain how it's supposed to work?

Comment: It's not the same issue. I am using `id` as a `key`

Comment: @JózefPodlecki No, you're using `idx` which is the array index: `<React.Fragment key={idx}>`. If you change it to be `<React.Fragment key={row.id}>` I think it would work.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not following. If you add say 3 inputs in your example and then try and remove the first input, its the last input that gets removed.

Comment: My bad, changed the key.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty common issue that is sometimes hard to wrap your head around. It has to do with how react manages dynamic elements like when returned from a `map`.

### The Problem

You're probably already seeing a warning that you should use a [`key`](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) when returning from `map`. When no `key` is given, react automatically uses the **index** of the array element. This is the root of the issue.

React uses this `key` to keep track of which element is which. So lets say you have a map that returns 3 divs. React will tag each of these divs with its `key` so it knows what needs updating in the future. The result will be the following:

```
<div key={0} val='a' />
<div key={1} val='b' />
<div key={2} val='c' />
```

This works fine for adding and updating. If you update the entry at index `1`, react will update the second element by identifying it by `key`.

The tricky scenario (like you have discovered) is deleting.

Let's say you delete the middle element. The resulting array will now only contain 2 positions. Now your JSX will look like this:

```
<div key={0} val='a' />
<div key={1} val='c' />
```

Maybe you can see what's happened already? You deleted the middle element, but to React, you have removed the last element and updated the second. Why? Because the `key` is based on the index, and the index has changed. React will unmount the `div` with a key of `2`, and keep the `div` with `key` of `1`. The second `div` has not been removed, but has been re-rendered with a new prop instead.

### The Solution

The root level fix is you need to provide a unique `key` to each element that will not change over time. The implementation of this may differ based on your use case.

For instance, if your list is guaranteed to have a unique value for each entry, you can use that. This is the simplest solution, but isn't always available.

A solution I have used in the past is to keep a counter in state that increments every time an element is added. I then use the counter to make an `id` for each element. That way, if an element is deleted, the `id` will not change.

### A Warning

A common mistake people make when faced with this problem is to generate a completely random `key` for each element using a helper function. This might stop the current issue, but is a very bad practice that might lead to future bugs. If the `key` changes every render, the element will unmount and remount every render. This won't have any side-effects in simple `div` example like this, but if your element is another component with state, it will lose its state. If your element is an input, it might lose focus every update. It's tempting, but **do not use a randomly generated number for the `key`**.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain this. I think I understand.