# Filter array by object value deletes the wrong object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

I'm using react with context and I want to delete an object. Here's my code

`Context.js`

```
  export const postsReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SET_POSTS":
      return {
        posts: action.payload,
      };
    case "CREATE_POST":
      return {
        posts: [action.payload, ...state.posts],
      };
    case "DELETE_POST":
      return {
        posts: state.posts.filter((post) => post._id !== action.payload._id),
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

And on my `Post.js`

```
  const { dispatch } = usePostsContext();

  const handleDelete = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("/api/posts/" + post._id, {
      method: "DELETE",
    });
    const json = await response.json();
    if (response.ok) {
      dispatch({
        type: "DELETE_POST",
        payload: json,
      });
      console.log(json);
    }
  };
```

The response `json` is this:

```
content: "zxczxc"
createdAt: "2024-01-25T01:58:43.088Z"
title: "zxczxc"
updatedAt: "2024-01-25T01:58:43.088Z"
__v: 0
_id: "65b1c0533b847bc475694dca"
```

This works, however it always deletes the last one in the array of `posts` and not the one filtered using the `._id`

UPDATE
Here's some additional code

```
    export const PostContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(postsReducer, { posts: null });

  return (
    <PostsContext.Provider value={{ ...state, dispatch }}>
      {children}
    </PostsContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Here's how I map the array
[image]

And the Delete button on the `Post` component
[image]

Comment: `it always deletes the last one in the array of posts` ... the usual suspect is a global or a `var` instead of a `let` or `const` somewhere in code you have NOT shown - is the `post._id` correct in `await fetch("/api/posts/" + post._id` - there's no indication what `post` even is in that code - that would be my guess

Comment: Usually when I see a bug related to always deleting last array element its due to using the index as a key for mapping https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62411951/unexpected-behavour-when-removing-an-item-from-an-array-in-react/62412342#62412342. Can't say for sure since the display code isn't included but it's something to check

Comment: I have updated the questions with additional codes

Answer (score -2):

Looks like the issue might be related to the way you are updating the state after fetching and deleting a post. When you dispatch the "DELETE_POST" action, you are passing the entire JSON response as the payload. Instead, you should pass the original post object's id that you want to delete.

Potential Solution:

```
const { dispatch } = usePostsContext();

const handleDelete = async () => {
  const response = await fetch("/api/posts/" + post._id, {
    method: "DELETE",
  });

  if (response.ok) {
    dispatch({
      type: "DELETE_POST",
      payload: { _id: post._id }, // Pass the post object's id for deletion
    });
  }
};
```